# Не получается передать метод что возвращает void в качестве аргумента другой метод

Tags: java, android, rxjava, lambda

Всем привет, есть небольшая проблема - не могу передать метод в качестве аргумента. (updateNotice)

Код класса с которого хочу передать:

```
public class NoticePresenter extends BasePresenter
    implements ILoadNoticePresenter, IUpdateNoticePresenter, IInsertNoticePresenter {

private INoticeView contract;
private IRoomNoticeModel roomNoticeModel;
private RoomDB database;

public NoticePresenter(Context context, INoticeView contract) {
    this.contract = contract;
    database = ((MyApplication)context.getApplicationContext()).getRoomInstance();
    roomNoticeModel = new RoomNoticeModel(database);
}

@Override
public void loadMyNotices(String userId) {
    contract.showLoading();
    if(contract!= null) {
        roomNoticeModel
                .getUserNotice(userId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new ConsumerSingleObserver<>(notices -> {
                    contract.hideLoading();
                    contract.loadListNotice(notices);
                }, throwable -> contract.showErrorLoading()));
    }
}

@Override
public void updateNotice(Notice notice){
    roomNoticeModel.sendQuery((method)-> database.noticeDao().updateNotice(notice));
    //databaseModel.updateUserNotice(notice);
}
```

Код класса что принимает:

```
public class RoomNoticeModel implements IRoomNoticeModel {
private RoomDB database;

public RoomNoticeModel(RoomDB roomDB) {
    database = roomDB;
}

@Override
public Single<List<Notice>> getUserNotice(String userId){
    return database.noticeDao().getAllNoticesUser(userId);
}

@Override
public void sendQuery(IntConsumer callable){
    Single.fromCallable(() -> callable)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe();
}
```

Результат передаю в udapteNotice лямбдою, на стадии компиляции ошибок нету - но при запуске этого метода выскакивает ошибка

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.notificeuserapp, PID: 9041
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.notificeuserapp.presenter.-$$Lambda$NoticePresenter$ZL-yPCo3nNsR6ndJTycxvnQHeNk
```

Скорее всего неправильный аргумент, но я не могу найти какой именно, подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему. Огромное спасибо заранее!)

Comment: Добрый вечер. Судя по ошибке java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, библиотеки, которая необходима для выполнения кода нет на устройстве. Ее надо добавить в архив с программой.

Comment: @Z.John в архиве не хватает файла `-$$Lambda$NoticePresenter$ZL-yPCo3nNsR6ndJTycxvnQHeNk.class`. Это класс из пользовательского кода.

Comment: Версия Android какая?